# Labels do not show on Parcel Fabric?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, parcel-fabric

I'm using the parcel fabric and I need to display the 'Distance' for each line of the drawing (it's a neighbourhood). I have to display only one value for each line of the block of lots, and so under 'Placement Properties' I have to select 'Remove duplicate labels'.

Another requirement is that the distance is set in meters, so I use the expression ´round([Distance],2)' - the result is 1.50, for example.

The problem is that some lots have lines that are not overlapping but they share a node (not the entire line) and simply do not appear. The reason I figured out is that when rounded they have the same 'value' and the ArcMap understands they are duplicate.

For other rounded values (x,xxx or 1,502, for example) it does not happen, but unfortunately I have to use the format 'x,xx'.

I'm using Arcmap 10.2.2.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from the inclusion of a picture that illustrates precisely what you are trying to do.  Also, as a new user please take the [Tour].